# Chrome loads js events before DOM loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I was doing some javascript testing on chrome v71.0.3578.98, with the `window.onload` and I'm experiencing the js happening before the DOM loads

Ref gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA1Ts.jpg

here is the code just wrapped in a simple html tag.

```html
<h1>Title...</h1>
<p>lorem500...</p>
<script>
  function pageLoad() {
    alert('I\'m alive');
  }
  window.onload = pageLoad;
</script>
```

So in this basic page I tried running it in chrome v71 and the javascript ran first, but in firefox, opera it loaded after page loaded, as expected. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `alert` *blocks* - while an `alert` popup is visible, further page rendering is prevented, and when `window.onload` runs, the page may well not have rendered at all yet, especially if there isn't much HTML at all before it. All elements *do* exist in the document when the `onload` runs, they just may not be visible. (It depends on the browser)

`alert` is very user-unfriendly, as well as being difficult to work with (as you're encountering). Use `console.log` or a proper modal instead:

```html
<h1>Title...</h1>
<p>lorem500...</p>
<script>
  function pageLoad() {
    console.log('I\'m alive');
  }
  window.onload = pageLoad;
</script>
```

If you *had* to use `alert`, only alert after an instant `setTimeout`, thus giving the browser a chance to paint the page before the `alert` gets called, just in case the browser hasn't rendered the page yet:

```html
<h1>Title...</h1>
<p>lorem500...</p>
<script>
  function pageLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('I\'m alive');
    });
  }
  window.onload = pageLoad;
</script>
```

Comment: yeah I ran a console, it worked, however I just was unsure the chrome responded differently than the event allows and other browsers load different as well. So which is it? the function with alert is before DOM or what?

Comment: It depends on the browser. Some browsers will paint before a blocking `alert` `onload`, some won't. Chrome is one of the ones that doesn't paint before the `alert`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that chrome was causing this behavior, so I have to keep that in mind when I allow alerts or figure a way this happens after DOM paints.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)